# CodeIgniter REST Server authentication problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

I'm using this [CodeIgniter REST Server](https://github.com/jpruiz114/codeigniter-restserver) project to implement a REST API.

So far I have been able to do some basic tests calling a controller via GET, PUT, POST and DELETE with keys.

Here's an example:

POST

```
curl -X POST -H "X-API-KEY: mAkS2FnJcXe8Whr8SbV0M6rJWMo3yNz6jgpV2ViL" http://jeanpaulruizvallejo.com/proyectos/pruebas/ci-rest-api/RestTestController/user/ --data "id=1"
```

Now, I need to be able to use username and passwords. I have tried with several ways but have not been able to get it working.

I would like to get some help about how to implement a username and password authentication model working for this REST API.

Thanks in advance for the help.

My current config file for rest:

[rest.php](https://gist.github.com/jpruiz114/4fcd60e3fbd2aefc9592)

Comment: this is an excellent recent tutorial on codeigniter rest server http://outergalactic.org/blog/restful-services-with-codeigniter/  note there is working code for the tutorial here: https://github.com/awhitney42/codeigniter-restserver-resources

Comment: Hey @cartalot I have read that tutorial before, and yes, it has excellent examples but has not solved my authentication problem. Anyway, I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: hi jean - my suggestion would be to look at some well documented APIs for different ways to do this. i'm an api noob, but i think that you could get the user name and password with post, validate them, and then issue a key which would function similar to a session id.

Comment: Hi @cartalot, the approach I'm using consists of having a non REST controller to authenticate, validate the username and the password, do a session handle and store the user key and from the server side, with Buzz (The php library) execute cURL calls. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: thanks i will check out Buzz library. also Guzzle is very popular for php curl etc - http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html on git https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Answer (score 1):

if you want a user login api key gen or user sign up based system, you can set a override auth config variable in rest.php config file.

Example : I want generate an api key when a user sign up with my controller "users" and my method "signup".

I simply add :

```
$config['auth_override_class_method']['users']['signup'] = 'none';
```

in

> ./application/config/rest.php
>   (see L.144)

That's all :) After this, you can generate a key in signup method and save the key in db before sending to client.

Another method should be to set a api key as token into session userdata and configure rest.php with the name of this variable.

I'm currently in the process of testing several of these methods and other implementations with codeigniter Rest.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AppleSt0rm, will test it and let you know the result.